# VF Error: Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded

Tags: apex, visualforce, viewstate

One of our VF page is based on a REST web-service which retrieves Service requests from Siebel in real-time. When number of records exceeds 1000, we were receiving below error because of which i added 'readonly' attribute in VF page component.
**'Content cannot be displayed: Collection size 1,582 exceeds maximum size of 1,000'**

Now we are getting view state error. And 'Internal' is occupying 210kb so not sure which ones I can make Transient. 
[image: ViewState]

I went through a post about this but didn't quite understand that. Below code is from Controller class, please help.

```
public class AccountServiceControllerExtension2 {

    public final Account acct{get; Set;}
    public String siebelId{get; set;}
    public String requestBody{get; set;}
    public String requestResult{get; set;}

    public list<list<String>> mainList{get; set;}
    public String pageUrl{get;set;}

    public Transient list<list<list<String>>> allList{get;set;}
    public list<list<String>> temp;
    public list<String> dataList1;
    public list<String> dataList2;
    public list<String> dataList3;
    public list<String> dataList4;
    public list<String> dataList5;

    public AccountServiceControllerExtension2(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        pageUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/apex/ServiceRequest2?id='+acct.id;


        List<Account> siebelIdLs=[select Siebel_Row_ID__c from Account where Id=:acct.id limit 1];
        siebelId='';
        if(siebelIdLs.size()==1)
        {
            if(siebelIdls.get(0).Siebel_Row_ID__c!=''&&siebelIdls.get(0).Siebel_Row_ID__c!=null){
                siebelId=siebelIdls.get(0).Siebel_Row_ID__c;
            }
        }

        String requestUrl='https://esbintg-m1.nit.oclc.org/services/getServiceRequest';

        String result='';
        Transient List<String> mresult = new List<String>();
        if(siebelId!='')
        {
            AccountHttpRequest ahr=new AccountHttpRequest();
            mresult=ahr.postCall(requestUrl,siebelId);
            if(mresult[0] == 'Success') 
            { 
                result = mresult[1];
                Transient List<map<String,String>> mapList=parseJason(result);   //get list data from json response
                if(mapList.size()>0)
                {
                    list<WebRequestMapListWrapper> wrapperList=new list<WebRequestMapListWrapper>();   

                    for(Integer i=0;i<mapList.size();i++){
                        WebRequestMapListWrapper wrapper1=new WebRequestMapListWrapper(mapList.get(i));
                        wrapperList.add(wrapper1);
                    }
                    wrapperList.sort();

                    mapList=new List<map<String,String>>();
                    //reverse order
                    for(Integer i = wrapperList.size()-1; i>=0;i--){
                        mapList.add(wrapperList.get(i).dataMap);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    requestResult='No data for this account.';
                }


                allList=new List<list<list<String>>>();     //Top level list for all rows
                list<String> dataList1=new List<String>();

                for(Integer i=0;i<mapList.size();i++)
                {
                    temp=new List<list<String>>();
                    dataList1=new List<String>();          //Bottom level list for real data
                    temp.add(dataList1);                  
                    allList.add(temp); 

                    if(mapList.get(i).get('abstract')==null) mapList.get(i).put('abstract','');
                    .
                    .
                    <code which Gets and Adds to the List>
                    .
                    .

                    dataList1.add('pageBlockTable'+String.valueOf(i)); //No.14

                }
            }       
            else
            { 
                requestResult = mresult[1];
            }
        }
        else
        {    requestResult='No Siebel Row ID.';
        }
    }   


    public list<map<String,String>> parseJason(String result)
    {   
        Map<String, String> amap=new Map<string, String>();

        List<map<String,String>> mapList=new List<map<String,String>>();
        if(result==''||result==null){
            return mapList;
        }

        Map<String, String> tempMap;

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(result);
        boolean flag=false;

        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {


            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)){
                String fieldName = parser.getText();


                if(flag){
                    if(fieldName=='abstract'){
                        tempMap = new Map<String, String>();
                        mapList.add(tempMap);
                        parser.nextToken();
                        tempMap.put('abstract',parser.getText());
                    }
                    .
                    .
                    <Statements which parses each token>
                    .
                    .
                }


                if(fieldName=='serviceRequest'){
                    flag=true;     
                    //System.debug('----------');
                }

            }

        }

        return mapList;

    }       
}
```

**And my VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountServiceControllerExtension2" readOnly="true" id="page">

    <style type="text/css">        

       .vfTableMainInfo {
            table-layout:fixed;
            word-wrap:break-word;
            overflow:hidden; 
            width: 50px;

        }

        .vfTable {
            table-layout:fixed;
            word-wrap:break-word;
            overflow:hidden; 
            width: 50px;

        }

        .expandFoldText{
            color: rgb(1,91,167);           
        }
        .expandFoldText1{
            color: rgb(1,91,167);           
        }       
        .expandFoldText2{
            color: rgb(1,91,167);    
            display: none;       
        }


    </style>


    <apex:form id="form">

    <apex:pageBlock id="main1" title="Service Data">    
              <apex:repeat id="repeat" value="{!allList}" var="innerList">

        <apex:pageBlockTable id="subTable1" value="{!innerList}" var="item" styleClass="vfTable">        



             <apex:column >

                     <label id="plus{!innerList[0][14]}" class="expandFoldText1" onmouseover="componentColorMouseOver(this);"  onmouseout="componentColorMouseOut(this);" onclick="expandProudct1(this,{!innerList[0][14]});" >(+)</label>
                     <label id="minus{!innerList[0][14]}" class="expandFoldText2" onmouseover="componentColorMouseOver(this);"  onmouseout="componentColorMouseOut(this);" onclick="expandProudct2(this,{!innerList[0][14]});">(-) </label>

                     {!item[0]}
                    <apex:facet name="header">                        
                       <label>Product</label>
                    </apex:facet> 
             </apex:column>


             <apex:column value="{!item[1]}">

                    <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>

             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!item[2]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Abstract</apex:facet>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!item[3]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Date Open</apex:facet>
             </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>     


        <div id="{!innerList[0][14]}" style="display:none">

        <apex:pageBlockTable id="subTable2" value="{!innerList}" var="item" styleClass="vfTable">               
             <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
             </apex:column>       
             <apex:column value="{!item[4]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!item[5]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">SR Number</apex:facet>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!item[6]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Date Closed</apex:facet>
             </apex:column>                           
        </apex:pageBlockTable>       

        <apex:pageBlockTable id="subTable3" value="{!innerList}" var="item" styleClass="vfTable">               
             <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
             </apex:column>       
             <apex:column value="{!item[7]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Resolution</apex:facet>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!item[8]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!item[9]}">
                    <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
             </apex:column>                           
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 


        </div>


        </apex:repeat>        
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

    <script>


          function hideAllHeader(){
            var headerList=document.getElementsByClassName("headerRow");
            tableList=document.getElementsByTagName("table");
            var aTable;                        
            var headers;

            var test=tableList[3];


          for (var i = 0; i < tableList.length; i++) {
            if((tableList[i].id!=="page:form:main1:repeat:0:subTable1")&&(tableList[i].id.indexOf("page:form:main1:repeat:")===0)){           
                headers=tableList[i].getElementsByTagName("thead");                
                for(var j =0; j<headers.length; j++){
                    headers[j].style.display="none";  
                }
               }                                            
            }
         }

         hideAllHeader();      

   </script>


    <script>
         window.onload = function(){
             hideAllHeader();               
         };   



         function componentColorMouseOver(component){
             //component.style.color="rgb(1,91,167)";
             component.style.color="red";
         }

         function componentColorMouseOut(component){
             //component.style.color="black";
             component.style.color="rgb(1,91,167)";
         }


         function expandProudct1(t, div){

             var headerId=div.id.replace("pageBlockTable","page:form:main1:repeat:"); //page:form:main1:repeat:0:subTable1
             var headerId1=headerId+":subTable1";
             var headerId2=headerId+":subTable2";

             var headerId3=headerId+":subTable3";

             var tableElem1=document.getElementById(headerId1);
             var headersElem1=tableElem1.getElementsByTagName("thead"); 
             var tableElem2=document.getElementById(headerId2);
             var headersElem2=tableElem2.getElementsByTagName("thead"); 
             var tableElem3=document.getElementById(headerId3);
             var headersElem3=tableElem3.getElementsByTagName("thead"); 


             var curDisplay=String(div.style.display);
             if(curDisplay==='none'){             
                 //expand/fold table
                 div.style.display="inline";        

                 t.style.display="none"; //hide/display plus and minus sine                 
                 document.getElementById(t.id.replace("plus","minus")).style.display="inline";    //hide/display plus and minus sine

                 //expand/fold table header
                 if(headerId1.indexOf("page:form:main1:repeat:0:subTable1")===-1){
                     for(var x1 =0; x1<headersElem1.length; x1++){
                         headersElem1[x1].style.display="table-row-group";  
                     }
                 }    
                 for(var x2 =0; x2<headersElem1.length; x2++){
                     headersElem2[x2].style.display="table-row-group";  
                 }  
                 for(var x3 =0; x3<headersElem1.length; x3++){
                     headersElem3[x3].style.display="table-row-group";  
                 }  

             }    

         }


         function expandProudct2(t, div){

             var headerId=div.id.replace("pageBlockTable","page:form:main1:repeat:"); //page:form:main1:repeat:0:subTable1
             var headerId1=headerId+":subTable1";
             var headerId2=headerId+":subTable2";
             var headerId3=headerId+":subTable3";

             var tableElem1=document.getElementById(headerId1);
             var headersElem1=tableElem1.getElementsByTagName("thead"); 
             var tableElem2=document.getElementById(headerId2);
             var headersElem2=tableElem2.getElementsByTagName("thead"); 
             var tableElem3=document.getElementById(headerId3);
             var headersElem3=tableElem3.getElementsByTagName("thead"); 

             var curDisplay=String(div.style.display);            
             if(curDisplay=='inline'){
                 div.style.display="none";
                 t.style.display="none"; 
                 document.getElementById(t.id.replace("minus","plus")).style.display="inline";   


                 //expand/fold table header

                 if(headerId1.indexOf("page:form:main1:repeat:0:subTable1")===-1){
                     for(var x1 =0; x1<headersElem1.length; x1++){
                         headersElem1[x1].style.display="none";  
                     }
                 }
                 for(var x2 =0; x2<headersElem1.length; x2++){
                     headersElem2[x2].style.display="none";  
                 }  
                 for(var x3 =0; x3<headersElem1.length; x3++){
                     headersElem3[x3].style.display="none";  
                 } 

             }      

         }
         function displayAllColumns(){
             document.getElementById("pageBlock1").style.display="none";    
             document.getElementById("pageBlock2").style.display="inline";    
         }

         function displayMainColumns(){
             document.getElementById("pageBlock2").style.display="none";    
             document.getElementById("pageBlock1").style.display="inline";    
         }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Service Requests are displayed like this.
[image: SRs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “internal” is overhead from the Visualforce `apex:`tags; the convenience of those tags comes at the cost of quite quickly consuming the available view state. Using plain HTML instead for the table rows is one workaround.

**PS**

If you open the page and use your browser's "View Page Source" option and search in that text you will find a hidden field with the name `com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState`. That is the view state that can't exceed the 135k limit (in it's server-side representation).

As your page doesn't have any input fields, removing the `<apex:form>` and `</apex:form>` tags will not affect the pagfe's functionality and will stop the view state from needing to be created and so stop the error whatever the number of rows is.